# did DIH support for invoking procedures

Tags: solr, dih

Did DIH support for invoking procedures? if it supported, how to configure it? I can't find it in wiki.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of. You have to write your own custom transformer, see http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DIHCustomTransformer

Comment: This is not what I mean. I mean invoking procedures instead of using sql, some logics code in procedure, so I must use procedure to query data.

Comment: @illu: yes, that's exactly what custom transformers are for: executing arbitrary code.

Comment: I still don't understand your meaning. IMO, transformer is used for callback. For example, 10 records are queried by DIH, so transformer will be called for 10 times, is this right?

Comment: and this is the method in class Transformer                   "
public Map<String, Object> transformRow(Map<String, Object> row, Context context)                "
it means you can get one row in parameter, and only return one row. If I use CallableStatement to invoke procedure in Transformer, how can I return the so many rows.

Comment: thanks for you help,  I've done it, It only need to change the return type of method transformRow to List<Map<String, Object>>. really thanks:)